# Accessible a powershell variable inside a function / workflow

Tags: powershell, variables, workflow

I am working on a Powershell script with a function and a Workflow. Unfortunately, I was unable to access variables inside the function. Here is an example :

```
$location = "c:\temp"

function PingComputer
{
     Param($ip)

     $res = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ip -quiet -Count 1 

     If ($res -eq "true") 
     {
          Try
          {
                #Some tasks if pings are ok
                #For example : copy-item -path $location -destination $dest -force -recurse
           }
           Catch
           {
           #Catch exceptions
           }
     }
     Else
     {
     #Ping fail
     }
  }

workflow parallelPingCOmputer {
Param($ips)
$i=0
foreach -parallel($ip in $ips)
{
    PingComputer($ip)
    $workflow:i++
    $count = $ips.Count
    InlineScript {
        #write-host "$using:i : " $using:ips.count " : $using:ips "
        Write-Progress -Activity "Poste : $using:ip" -Status "Postes effectués : $using:i sur $using:count" -PercentComplete (($using:i / $using:Count) * 100)
        sleep -s 1
        }

     }
}

$request = parallelPingComputer -ips $ip_list | Select-object date, computer, result | out-gridview
```

This is a simplified version of my current script. But, as you can see, the variable $location can't be accessed inside my function PingComputer. I tried to modify its scope as global or script, but nothing works.

The message I get with the copy-item is "path is null"... How can I make my variable accessible ?

Comment: Insert the function inside the workflow and not outside.

Comment: Thank's for this advice. Unfortunally, i was unable to insert my function inside my workflow... Is it possible to you to help me to perform that ?

Comment: Is there a reason not to make `$location` a parameter of PingComputer and just give it a default value matching what you're wanting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the function, just copy the function inside the workflow and keep it outside. Else, copy the function inside the workflow and remove the one outside like the code below. It could solve your problem without using a function inside the workflow.

I made an [example on my Github](https://github.com/ManuProd/PowershellWorkflow) :

```
Workflow Get-Ping{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string[]]$Computers
    )

    Foreach -Parallel ($computer in $Computers){
        $ping = $null
        $version = $null
        if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet){
            $ping = "Online"
            $version = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class "Win32_OperatingSystem" -PSComputerName $computer | select Version
        }
        else{
            $ping = "Offline"
        }

        #if no gwmi use -ComputerName $computer
        $arrayResults = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            Hostname = $computer
            Ping = $ping
            Version = $version.Version
        }
    return($arrayResults)
    }
}

$computers = Get-Content ".\Computers.txt"
Write-Host "$($computers.Count) computers found" -ForegroundColor Green

Get-Ping -Computers $computers | Select-Object Hostname, Ping, Version | Sort-Object Hostname | Out-GridView -Title "Powershell Workflow - Ping"
```

Comment: Thank's for that example. I need to include a variable which is located outside the workflow... how can I done this ? It's a copy-item, where the path is retrieved from a "folder-picker".